# get function name and its parameters passed to a function

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a `display` function which I want to use it as follows:

```
display(min(1,10))

//expected output
min(1,10)
```

I am not able to get the name of the function and its parameters as is from the `arguments` object. I have started out like this.

```
function display() {
    return arguments[0];
}

display(min(1,10));

//expected output
min(1,10)

//actual output
1
```

I understand that the `min` function is getting evaluated and its value is being taken as the first argument.

Short of wrapping the `min` function inside quotes, is there nothing we can do to get the passed function name and its parameters?

```
display('min(1,10)');

//expected output
min(1,10)

//actual output
min(1,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the `min` function is getting evaluated and its value is being taken as the first argument.

Correct.

> Short of wrapping the `min` function inside quotes, is there nothing we can do to get the passed function name and its parameters?

No, nothing. By the time the value gets to `display`, there is nothing about it that associates it with where it came from (the result of calling `min(1, 10)`).

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for taking time to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function min(a,b){
return 1;
}
function display() {
    return arguments[0];
}

console.log(display(min));
```

`min(1,10)` will return the value first then it will go into display function.